# Href Link Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I am trying to add a a link as part of the Product.Text but I've horribly got it wrong here, doing this on the C-Sharp code behind.

```
tcProduct.Text = "<div class=\"productname\">" + "<a class=\"productnameLink\" href=\"item.Product.Url\">" + item.Product.Name + "</a>" + "</div>";
```

The backward slashes are beginning to confuse me. Instead of a normal hyperlink i guess i should be using the .NET hyperlink instead??

I've tried this but doesn't add the hyperlink;

```
            HyperLink productNameLink = new HyperLink();
            productNameLink.Text = "<div class=\"productname\">" + item.Product.Name + "</div>"; 
            productNameLink.NavigateUrl = item.Product.Url.ToString();
            productNameLink.CssClass = "prodNameLink";
            tcProduct.Controls.Add(productNameLink);
```

Comment: what kind of control is `tcProduct` ?

Comment: *..backward slashes are beginning to confuse me..*: Use single quotes then, for attributes. Also, tried using `.InnerHtml` instead of `.Text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain string formatting should do the trick:

```
tcProduct.Text = string.Format("<div class=\"productname\"><a class=\"productnameLink\" href=\"{0}\">{1}</a></div>", 
    item.Product.Url, item.Product.Name);
```

However, you really better use a Repeater which is meant exactly for such things. Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><h1>Products</h1></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="productname"><a class="productnameLink" href="<%# Eval("Url") %>"><%# Eval("Name") %></a></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code behind:

```
rptProducts.DataSource = arrProducts;
rptProducts.DataBind();
```

Where `arrProducts` is the collection of your products.

Answer (score 2):

What i used to do that is ASP Literal.

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then in the code set to it with

```
Literal2.Text = "<a class='productnameLink' href=" + item.Product.Url + ">" + item.Product.Name + "</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Panel** control which renders as **div**.

```
var link = new HyperLink
{
    Text = item.Product.Name,
    NavigateUrl = item.Product.Url.ToString(),
    CssClass = "prodNameLink"
};
var panel = new Panel
{
    CssClass = "productname"
};
panel.Controls.Add(link);
tcProduct.Controls.Add(panel);
```

### Output:

```
<div class="productname">
   <a class="prodNameLink" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Text property is supposed to be text only.
Many ways to do what you need to, but if you want to stick to using html string you could use:

```
tcProduct.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl
        {
            InnerHtml = string.Format(@"<div class=""productname""><a class=""productnameLink"" href=""{0}"">{1}</a></div>", item.Product.Url, item.Product.Name )
        });
```

Bonus, you can get rid of the '\' escape char with averbatim string literal: @"" (you need to double the quotes).